# Why did Hyperion stop bombing Sanctuary?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the mission *Bright Lights, Flying City*, after losing its shields and getting bombed by Hyperion, Sanctuary, as foreshadowed by the mission name becomes a flying city.

[image: screenshot of Hyperion station and sanctuary floating in the sky/space]

Why did Hyperion then suddenly stop bombing Sanctuary?

Comment: Considering they were launching the bombs from a space station near the moon, it would have been pretty hard to hit a moving city compared to a stationary one.

Comment: @SaintWacko Sanctuary seems to be stationary after the move, just displaced.

Comment: Also, spotting a city from space, even with today's technology shouldn't be so hard, should it? With line of sight, what is the in-game explanation for Hyperion not being able to bomb Sanctuary any more?

Comment: I don't think there ever was a great reason given. I always assumed that the energy core that Angel used to hack the shields of the stationary city was also used as a beacon of sorts, so the space station knew where to shoot. Now, having travelled so far away from the beacon, the space station can't aim correctly anymore.

Comment: I don't remember the exact dialog, but I got the impression that Jack didn't know where the city went. Didn't it also get shields at that point?

Comment: Trying to figure this out. There's a walkthrough of the game on YouTube, by Major Slack. You can see the city disappear at the end of Rising Action at about 7 minutes into [Part 79](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8F_9KeVzcw). You can see the city reappear during Bright Lights, Flying City about 3:15 into [part 87](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48mnzBtHYgM). At the moment, I'm thinking they start shooting when the shields go down, and that the shields are back up once it jumps.

Comment: @DCShannon I don't know why the shields would be up though, as you just replaced the power core with the fake/Hyperion one. Then again, the first time you reach Sanctuary, the bombing stops just as the shield power core is replaced. Maybe the shields are up, and I missed something.

Comment: Then again, that would make the jump redundant.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga I couldn't find any clear evidence that the shields were back up from watching videos, but that's the only explanation I have that really makes sense. The only reason they weren't already shooting is because the shields were up. It might be out of range, or at a bad angle, but we can still see the moon base in the sky, so that doesn't seem super likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lilith contacts Hyperion on an open ECHO channel after you reach Sanctuary again, inviting them to go ahead and try. But she reminds them that every projectile they fire costs Hyperion billions of credits, and she can always teleport the city again. (She later admits to Roland that she probably can't - it took a lot out of her, and she might just as likely 'port the city into a mountain - but of course she'd never tell Hyperion that.)

I'm guessing you will end up missing this conversation if you turn in "Bright Lights, Flying City" to Roland without stopping to listen.

Comment: I must have missed this dialogue (thanks to other players accepting missions or initiating fast-travel). I'll try to find a video/transcript of it, or if that fails, listen for it next time I reach that part in the campaign (which shouldn't be too long now).

Comment: I just reached Sanctuary, and heard no such conversation. Could you be more specific / link to a video maybe?

Comment: Sorry for late reply - unfortunately, I don't have a character handily about to re-enter Sanctuary, so I can't look for the exact text. I just know it's a scene in HQ, with Lilith and maybe Roland around the map table. ISTR Lilith isn't addressing Jack directly, but rather is making a general announcement to Hyperion.

Comment: Just now reached Sanctuary with Krieg on UVHM, and listened to that conversation again. It's definitely there.

Comment: Where in the story is it exactly? First time coming back to Sanctuary after the jump? Where or when is the trigger for the conversation? Because like I mentioned, I specifically went looking for this conversation and wasn't able to find it. I even had my screen recorder set up to get it on video.

Comment: Set up the beacon in Overlook to re-establish Sanctuary on the Fast Travel network, visit Sanctuary, run up to HQ, and just listen. That's all I ever had to do.

Comment: I'll give it another shot with my next character :)

Comment: Good hunting! I've recently returned to the game after a couple-year hiatus. I have this thing about collections, and I'm obsessed with getting as many of the skins as I can.

Answer (score -2):

first off jack is PAYING hyperion to do this and they would have to completly realign the cannon the gap/time between then and endgame is so short.